# What is the opposite operation to distribution called?

Tags: terminology, boolean-algebra

When you perform this operation from left to right:
$$a\lor(b\land c)\iff(a\lor b)\land(a\lor c)$$
It's called distribution, right?
So what is the opposite operation called? From right to left?

Comment: Other way around. The latter is distribution, the former is factorization. At least in regular algebra.

Comment: It's the same property no matter what you write it because logical equivalence is symmetric. I've never heard it called anything other than distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distribution is the very equivalence between the two statements, so both going left to right and going right to left is Distribution.

And yes, clearly the left-to-right direction is more intuitively called Distribution than right-to-left, so often I refer to the right-to-left part as 'Reverse Distribution', 'Factoring', or 'Collecting Common Terms'.  But again, technically it really is just Distribution.

Answer (score 2):

The only term I know for this is factoring, analogous to the operation that takes $ab+ac$ to $a(b+c)$ by "factoring out" the $a$.  A Google Books search on "boolean algebra" "factorize" or "factorization" shows several books that use this terminology.